# Not to allow to delete models in django project for demo product

Tags: django, django-admin, django-middleware

I have a demo product built on django framework and is running live. Prospective customer will login to the UI with superuser access privilege. I wanted to show the delete option but when they execute the delete option, I want to show the message like 'not allowed for demo login'.

Is there a way to achieve this quickly in django framework. What is the best option to do this.

Thanks
Siva

Comment: did you mean the django's admin interface by `the UI`? Or you write the UI yourself?

Comment: why don't you mimic a delete with javascript (hide), so they get the experience?

Comment: did you try to override the delete() method? check for type demo user, and return error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a demo user and adding the following code to the middleware class:

```
                    if request.user.username == 'demo':
                            if '/delete' in path:
                                    request.user.message_set.create(message='Delete/Edit option is disabled for demo account.')
                                    return HttpResponseRedirect("../../")
                            if path.startswith ('/admin/') and request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.has_key('action'):
                                    axnname   = request.POST.get('action')
                                    if axnname == 'delete_selected':
                                            request.user.message_set.create(message='Delete/Edit option is disabled for demo account.')
                                            return HttpResponseRedirect(path)
                            if path.startswith ('/admin/') and request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax() is False:
                                    request.user.message_set.create(message='Add/Edit option is disabled for demo account.')
                                    return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a staff user, definitely not a superuser. This will let you take advantage of Django's builtin permissions, which seems convenient in your case.

Create a user that has permissions to Add and Edit DemoModel, *not* Delete.

Add a JS file to your change_form via [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects), or [add a custom view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls)

```
class DemoModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = (
            '/static/js/mimic_delete.js',
        )

admin.site.register(DemoModel, DemoModelAdmin)
```

In your mimic_delete.js file you can add a jQuery loop to add a delete button to each row in the results_list of the DemoModel changeform and add a hide event onclick or whatever you'd like for a representation.

Another approach could be to bind the model entries to a session and override the ModelAdmin's get_queryset to filter the entries that where created by the user in the current session, cleaning them up after the session expired.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Mine is a bit complex product, has hundreds of models and multiple applications. I dont want to change the code at multiple places. I want to have the changes in 1 place. Say either in the middleware by capturing the URLs or in the django's options.py file that takes care of the delete work.